# Is it legal in Denmark to deface religious scriptures?

Tags: criminal-law, religion, denmark, blasphemy

This piece from the New York times got my attention: https://mobile.nytimes.com/2017/02/23/world/europe/denmark-quran-burning.html

Apparently some Danish guy got convicted of burning the Quran.

Q. What rights do the Danish people have in terms of burning other religious artifacts like the Bible?

Comment: Actually, he is being prosecuted. The last conviction was is 1946.

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.anklagemyndigheden.dk/nyheder/Sider/tiltalt-for-afbraending-af-koranen.aspx (from what I understand through Google translate, it is the official government website of the public prosecution, see: http://www.anklagemyndigheden.dk/Sider/vores-organisation.aspx )

The prosecution said:

> Det er anklagemyndighedens opfattelse, at omstændighederne i forbindelse med afbrænding af hellige bøger som Bibelen og Koranen indebærer, at det i visse tilfælde kan være en overtrædelse af blasfemiparagraffen, der handler om offentlig spot eller forhånelse i forhold til en religion

Translated:

> It is the prosecution's view that the circumstances surrounding the burning of holy books like the Bible and the Qur'an imply that it may in some cases be a violation of the blasphemy provision, which deals with public mockery or insult against a religion.

so I would say that it is reasonable to expect that burning a Bible would lead to the same outcome as in this case, i.e. Danes are not allowed to burn holy books, regardless of religion.

---

The "blasphemy provision" is, as said [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blasphemy_law#Denmark), paragraph 140, [that reads](https://www.retsinformation.dk/Forms/R0710.aspx?id=181992):

> Den, der offentlig driver spot med eller forhåner noget her i landet lovligt bestående religionssamfunds troslærdomme eller gudsdyrkelse, straffes med bøde eller fængsel indtil 4 måneder.

Translated:

> One who publicly mocks or insults any here in the country legally existing religious community's religious teachings or worship is punished with a fine or prison of up to four months.

Comment: This answer would be much better if you can cite what the actually blasphemy provision is (I know it can be challenging though since its all in Danish and not in English).

Comment: Actually, I think this will get you where you need to go: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blasphemy_law#Denmark

Comment: @DavidGrinberg added, feel free to adjust the translation, if you think you can help. thanks.